# Row Height of UITableView Custom Cell doesn't update, Swift iOS8

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, custom-cell, xcode6.4

I have created a UITableView Custom Cell in the Storyboard in Xcode 6.4 in iOS 8. When I change the row height in the Size Inspector [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXTH0.png) of the Storyboard nothing happens to the custom cells of my UITableView in the App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update it with override this method in your `TableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 55
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this way, but I have several different cells with different heights in my UITableView

Comment: @PhilippJanuskovecz You can return different values for every cell with using 'indexPath'

Answer (score 0):

In this method of your tableview controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell?
```

Make sure to add this line:

```
cell.height = yourHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adding Table View Cell Prototype in Table View on Storyboard and dragging bottom your Prototype Cell and you can get height cell what do you want.